# check if commands contain string or empty

Tags: linux, sh

I want to write a shell script to check if the first param is empty or contains the string "task". 
I tried:

```
if [ -z "$*" ] || [$1 != *"task"*] ; then
    echo "Empty or not contains task"
else
    echo "Contains task"
```

But it is not correct.
I even tried to break down the condition:

```
if [ -z "$*" ] ; then
    echo "empty"
elif [$1 != *"task"*] ; then
    echo "Not contains task"
else
    echo "Contains task"
```

The empty condition is correct but the condition check on contains string not correct.
Anyone knows how to fix it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enjoy

```
if [[ -z "$*" || $1 != "task" ]] ; then
  echo "Empty or not contains task"
else
  echo "Contains task"
fi
```